# selenium webdriver .Net chrome upload file

Tags: c#, selenium, upload, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**How to upload file with Selenium WebDriver in Chrome .NET**.

Version Chrome (20.0.1132.57). Version chromedriver 22.0.1203.0b

Code:

```
driver.GetElement(someXpath).SendKeys(filePath)
```

throws exception:

`Element is not clickable at point (144, 90.5). Other element would receive the click: <h2>...</h2>`

HTML-code:

```
<a class="button addfile"> Upload <input class="fileupload" type="file" multiple="" name="files[]"/> </a>
```

Comment: Is the element that is not clickable disabled at any point beforehand? If so it could be that you need to add a wait command before the SendKeys()

Comment: this element is enable and visible on page in that moment

Comment: In FireFox this code worked right, but I need run my test in Chrome

Comment: @AnvarRamazanov did you solve this issue? I've just encountered it too.

Comment: what does your XPATH look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can force the element to be visible using JavaScript.  For the input element, execute JavaScript using the IJavaScriptExecutor, and set the visibility of the element visible, and for good measure, give it some dimensions.

```c#
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; 
arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileUploadElement);
```